# ASP.Net MVC : Get query values with no key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

I have URL: http://site.com/page.aspx?update

how do I check if that update value is present?

`HttpValueCollection` treats that as an entity with `null` key. I have tried:

```
var noKeyValues = Request.QueryString.GetValues(null);
if (noKeyValues != null && noKeyValues.Any(v=>v==update)) ...
```

but it gives me a frowny line, because GetValues' argument is decorated with [NotNull].

so I end up doing:

```
    var queryValuesWithNoKey =
            Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Select((key, index) => new { key, value = Request.QueryString.GetValues(index) }).Where(
                    item => item.key == null).Select(item => item.value).SingleOrDefault();
    if (queryValuesWithNoKey != null && queryValuesWithNoKey.Any(v => v.ToLower() == "update")) live = true;
```

not the most elegant workaround. Is there a better way to get key-less value from query string?

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
Request.QueryString[null]
```

to retrieve a comma separated list of keys with no values.  For instance, if your url is:

`http://mysite/?first&second`

then the above will return

```
first,second
```

In your case, you could just do something like:

```
if(Request.QueryString[null] == "update") 
{
    // it's an update
}
```

Comment: I stil get warning `argument decorated with [NotNull]` if I don't mind that - I can as well use `Request.QeryString.GetValues(null)`. I wonder if warning is baseless, since I don't see [NotNull] on the argument.

Comment: Yeah I think the same thing.  It all seems to work OK, so I'm not worrying too much about the warning.

Answer (score 1):

if that's the only key you would use

Request.QueryString.ToString() to get the "update" value

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but this a function that I use for this kind of task.

```
internal static bool HasQueryStringKey(HttpRequestBase request, string key)
{
    // If there isn't a value, ASP will not recognize variable / key names.
    string[] qsParts = request.QueryString.ToString().Split('&');
    int qsLen = qsParts.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < qsLen; i++)
    {
        string[] bits = qsParts[i].Split('=');
        if (bits[0].Equals(key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

You may need to update it so that it is case sensitive, or uses different arguments depending on your purposes, but this has always worked well for me.

Comment: I cannot speak for the proc/cons of this solution, but here a one liner of it `return request.QueryString.ToString().Split('&').Select(parts => parts.Split('=')).Any(bits => bits[0].Equals(key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`